# List of EOSIO related telegram channels

Tags: dapp

Most of the EOS.IO community is active on the Telegram communications platform. Can we produce a list of all the appropriate Telegram group chats related to EOS.IO?

Answer (score 3):

**General Note: please keep transparent who added which link.**

## General

- EOS https://t.me/EOSproject
- Worbli https://t.me/worblicommunity
- Telos https://t.me/HelloTelos
- WAX https://t.me/wax_io
- BOS https://t.me/boscorecommunity
- EOS Price Discussions https://t.me/EOSPrice
- Scatter https://t.me/Scatter

## For developers

- EOS Developers https://t.me/joinchat/DQRZHEPktgcLlyfbl-bDuQ
- EOS Jungle Testnet https://t.me/jungletestnet
- EOS Block Pros https://t.me/EOSPros
- Bancor Developers https://t.me/BancorDevelopers
- EOS Kylin Testnet https://t.me/cryptokylin1en
- EOS Mechanics https://t.me/EOSMechanics
- DAPP Network Devs https://t.me/joinchat/GTxt3lEL6HLeFzgsWA87qg
- EOS Infra https://t.me/eosinfra

## Governance

- EOS Governance https://t.me/EOSGov
- EOS Voter Proxies https://t.me/eosproxies
- EOS Mainnet Status https://t.me/eosmainnetstatus

## Block Producers

- EOS New York https://t.me/eosnewyorkchat
- EOS Cafe Block https://t.me/eoscafeblock
- EOS42 https://t.me/EOS42
- EOS Asia https://t.me/EOSAsia

## Proxies

- Brock Pierce Proxy https://t.me/Brockpierce1

## Dapps

- EOS Voice https://t.me/eosvoice
- WIZZ CHAT https://t.me/wizznetwork
- Lumeos https://t.me/lumeos
- Chestnut https://t.me/chestnutEOS
- dGoods https://t.me/dGoods_EOS
- REX https://t.me/eosrex
- Chintai https://t.me/ChintaiEOS
- Hirevibes https://t.me/hirevibes_dapp

## News and announcements

- EOS Go Community Updates https://t.me/eosgo_news
- EOS Radio https://t.me/EOSRadioUpdates
- EOS Go Turbo Updates https://t.me/eosgo_turbo
- The WIRE https://t.me/eosLAUNCHbyTHEwire

## Miscellaneous

- EOS Jobs https://t.me/eos_jobs